# Custom filter in Angular.js with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json like this

```
[
    {
        "itemId": 1062,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "Modern Martial Arts Vitor Shaolin Brazilian Jiu Jitsu",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/modern-martial-arts-vitor-shaolin-brazilian-jiu-jitsu-new-york",
        "rating": 5,
        "city": "New York",
        "address": "780 8th Ave (b/t 47th St & 48th St) Hell's Kitchen New York NY 10036",
        "imageUrl": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/JHk9p_jYX1QpQN4Im-p3jA/ms.jpg",
        "source": "Yelp",
        "longitude" : -42.005,
        "latitude" : 65.007,
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 8227,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "TGA of Bergen County",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.golftga.com/Default.aspx?alias=www.golftga.com/bergencounty",
        "city": "Wayne",
        "address": "17 North Jersey Lane Wayne NJ 07470 USA",
        "source": "Groupon",
        "longitude" : -42.005,
        "latitude" : 65.007,
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 3932,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "Willowbrook Golf Center",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.willowbrookgolfcenter.com",
        "city": "North Jersey",
        "address": "17 North Jersey Lane Wayne NJ 07470 USA",
        "source": "Groupon",
        "longitude" : -42.005,
        "latitude" : 65.007,
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 3918,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "Church Street Boxing Gym & Pouncing Tigers",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.csboxinggym.com/",
        "city": "New York City",
        "address": "201207 West 42nd Street New York NY 10036 USA",
        "source": "Groupon",
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 1100,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "CKO Kickboxing Carroll Gardens",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/cko-kickboxing-carroll-gardens-brooklyn-2",
        "rating": 4,
        "city": "Brooklyn",
        "address": "562 Court St (b/t Hamilton Ave & Garnet St) Carroll Gardens Brooklyn NY 11231",
        "imageUrl": "http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/guwuh08U_tYTyRsjLQIJ-w/ms.jpg",
        "source": "Yelp",
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 462,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "TITLE Boxing Club",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.titleboxingclub.com",
        "city": "Wayne",
        "address": "Wayne NJ 07470 USA",
        "source": "Groupon",
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 474,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "Centercourt Athletic Club of Morristown",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.centercourtclub.com/club/scripts/section/section.asp?CLNK=1&NS=CMT",
        "city": "Wayne",
        "address": "Wayne NJ 07470 USA",
        "source": "Groupon",
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 3326,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "Legends Baseball Instruction",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.legendsbaseballinstruction.com",
        "city": "North Jersey",
        "address": "17 North Jersey Lane Wayne NJ 07470 USA",
        "source": "Groupon",
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Self",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Gaurav",
            "lastName": "Shandilya",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/1_1401692790212_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 1104,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "Adirondack Sailing",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/adirondack-sailing-new-york",
        "rating": 4,
        "city": "New York",
        "address": "62 Chelsea Piers New York NY 10011",
        "imageUrl": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/FwpUOlPWSpLlEteBGukcpg/ms.jpg",
        "source": "Yelp",
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Friend",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 4,
            "firstName": "Ashish",
            "lastName": "Chandra",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/4_1400934645640_Ashish"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemId": 1709,
        "businessType": "SPORT",
        "name": "Manhattan Sailing Club",
        "websiteUrl": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/manhattan-sailing-club-new-york",
        "rating": 4,
        "city": "New York",
        "address": "385 S End Ave Ste 6H Battery Park New York NY 10280",
        "imageUrl": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/9yvzeSYaKfguvDUzF69xvw/ms.jpg",
        "source": "Yelp",
        "itemType": "Business",
        "suggestionCriteria": "like",
        "suggestedBy": "Friend",
        "suggestingUser": {
            "userId": 4,
            "firstName": "Ashish",
            "lastName": "Chandra",
            "imageUrl": "http://54.243.29.6:8080/UploadedImages/4_1400934645640_Ashish"
        }
    }
]
```

I am showing this in a list by the help of ng-repeat . I wanna make a custom filter where user can filter the list on basis of distance (if long and lat are there) from his current position , price , ratings and suggested by (self or frd)
Please help me to find the solution

Here is the [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8ArGO1OvT7FHIV1ixSEA?p=preview)

Comment: you already did, build a custom filter and then apply it to the list

Comment: That is what i want to know how to make custom filter for this much properties ?

Comment: first post what you already have on jsbin or jsfiddle it makes it easier to add to the code than having to copy yours and start a new one. second are those filters compounded meaning if the user start to filter by price and get a set back then by ratings should the expected results be filtered by price and ratings or does it trigger a new search?

Comment: I have updated question with plunker link

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as the first argument to `filter` for a more complex filter. For example you can specifiy in your controller:

```
    $scope.filterFn = function (o) {
        return (o.price > 10) && ((o.longitude - user.longitude) < 2) && (o.itemType === 'Business');
    }
```

your filter function will receive the current list item as its first argument. If it returns `true` the filtered list will contain the current item.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter (`expression` argument as function) for more information

Comment: Thanks for reply . Can you please edit my plunker for rating filter